# Ocultar una fila en mat-table Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando una tabla en Angular material, y deseo ocultar una fila pero sin borrarla. La idea es ocultar la fila y seguidamente crear un nuevo div que aparezca con los datos anteriores de la fila, con motivo de crear una edición en la misma linea. Quizás se pueda realizar de otro modo pero no se me ocurre cual. Si puedo ocultar la linea quizás esta sea la forma viable de realizarlo.

Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Deberías añadir el código del componente para que podamos ayudarte. Por otro lado, Angular te permite trabajar de un modo distinto, donde el modelo y los datos están más desacoplados: quizá "borrar" la fila sea la opción más sencilla

Comment: No tengo código hecho, ya que estoy haciendo las pruebas con el propio que está en angular material, No he podido avanzar porque no encuentro la forma, ni siquiera tengo una idea clara de como comenzar. He intentado varias formas en javascript pero no se me han adaptado al mat-table y no me han funcionado.  https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo entender a lo que te refieres; sin embargo pienso que sería mejor mostrar/ocultar elementos dentro de la row de la tabla utilizando el `ngIf`, y no en sí la row. Ej:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="datos">

    <!-- Columna (angular material table) -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="columna1">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Columna 1 </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">

            <span *ngIf="enEdicion">
                <input type="text" name="columna1" [(ngModel)]="element.columna1">
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!enEdicion">
                {{element.columna1}}
            </span>

        </td>
    </ng-container>

</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido. No había pensado en esta posibilidad de un condicional.